# How to place an attributed epigraph on a "part" page?

Tags: parts, epigraphs

I'm using the `memoir` class together with the `epigraph` package to put some awesome/cheesy/YMMV*/YOMV** quotes at the beginning of each chapter. This works great and looks quite neat.

I now also want to place some nice bits of text on the `part` pages, and found this little bit of code in the package's manual:

```
% epipart.sty
\let\@epipart\@endpart
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{\thispagestyle{epigraph}\@epipart}
\endinput
```

Which allows me to do

```
epigraphhead[300]{Epigraph text}
\part{Part title}
```

Unfortunately, this does not allow for the second argument of the epigraph, which I use for the attribution. Is there a way to get this on the part pages?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{epipart}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[400]{This is a half-baked solution}
\part{One}

\chapter{One}
\epigraph{this works great}{me -- about everything I do}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

---

* Your Mileage May Vary

** Your Opinion May Vary

Comment: @barbara you are correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility, defining a `\partepigraph` command with the following syntax

```
\partepigraph[<voffset>]{<text>}{<attribution>}
```

The idea (see `memoir`'s manual, Section **13.3.1 Epigraphs on book or part pages** on page 256) is to hook into `memoir`'s `\afterpartskip`. Use  `\partepigraph{}{}` before `\part` and then \removeepigraph immediately after `\part`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\let\oldafterpartskip\afterpartskip % save definition

\newcommand\partepigraph[3][60pt]{
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{%
\vskip#1
\epigraph{#2}{#3}
\vfil}
}
\newcommand\removeepigraph{%
  \let\afterpartskip\oldafterpartskip} % restore definition

\begin{document}

\partepigraph{this works great}{me -- about everything I do}
\part{An epigraphed part}
\removeepigraph

\part{An unepigraphed part}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

By the way, `memoir` internally loads the `epigraph` package, so you don't need to load it explicitly in your document.